# Retrieving Address from Function

Tags: excel, vba

Creating a Function in Excel VBA. The Function input names the variable (Price) and returns the value from the cell location input, but I also need the location of the cell from which to offset a specific set of N rows to create a cell location for other parts of the calculation. The function starts with the following:

```
Function nKAMA(Price, FastN, SlowN, N)
```

Price is input as reference to a cell location and returns the value of the cell. The other variables are integer inputs used in the calculation.

I want to be able to obtain the current Price cell's "A1" style address to reference other cells for the calculations

Comment: `Price.Address` or you can directly offset using `Price.Offset(numofRows, numofCols)`

Comment: Works perfectly for my purposes. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use data types in the definition so you know what is what.

For example:

```
Function nKAMA(ByRef Price as Range, ByVal FastN as Single, ByVal SlowN as Single, Byval N as Long) as Single

    Debug.Print Price.Address

End Function
```